# dynamic SSL certificate with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, devops

I have a multi-tenant eCommerce platform.(my customer can create their own eCommerce website)
after create a store, each customer get subdomain `customer-store-name.myapp.com`,

To handle this SSL use case(`xxx.myapp.com`) I could use wildcard ssl (*.myapp.com).

However, I have to allow them to connect their own custom domain.
for example `customer.com` ===> `customer-store-name.myapp.com`

If I worked with `nginx` as proxy pass,I guess I could write some automation to create certificate for each customer with some backend service using `lets encrypt` and then add block for each customer to `conf.d`

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name customer.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/customer.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/customer.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://eCommerce:80/;
        ...
    }
}
```

However in this case I have to restart the nginx each time I add customer. and it could be a large list of domains.

So, is there any services on `aws` which could solve my requirements? or any combination of services to solve it?

(if there is any service outside `aws` it could be ok too)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not an easy solution to fulfil this problem.

Your SSL options are the following:

- Generate an SSL containing all domain names, this would be attached to an ALB/NLB with TLS/CloudFront distribution.
- Generate a new SSL via Lets Encrypt (like you said) for each domain name.

The problem with any of these solutions is they require you to gain authorisation from the customers domain admin to allow you to generate these SSL certificates.

I would suggest using ACM over the Lets Encrypt method as it allows you to easily scale your application a demand increases. There is currently a default quota of 10 domains per ACM SSL so you will need to contact AWS to have this limit increased (wildcards count as 1 domain).